# Solve $x$ such that $x^q-b = 0$ mod $p$ efficiently

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How do u solve for $x$ if  $x^q-b = 0$ mod $p$, $p$ and $q$ are known primes and $b$ is a known integer.

This is what I'm thinking, I can rewrite the equation to $x^q = b$ mod $p$ then permute $x$ and compare it to see if I get $b$ mod $p$.

However is there a more efficient way of computing the value of $x$?

Comment: Rather depends on whether $q\mid(p-1)$ or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$x^q \equiv b \pmod{p}   \Rightarrow x^{qc} \equiv b^c \pmod{p}$$

Can you find a  $c$ such that $x^{qc} \equiv x \pmod{p}$?

Comment: sorry i don't really get how $qc = 1$ mod $p$ is linked to my question

Comment: @albusSimba: It isn't, since $qc \equiv 1 \pmod p$ *doesn't* imply $x^{qc} \equiv x \pmod p$. But you're very close. I'll give you another hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function

Comment: So it's $\phi(n)=n-1 =qc-1$? And I assume $c$ is known?